# Class method template argument list

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template method declared in my interface:

```
class IObjectFactory
{
public:
    virtual ~IObjectFactory() { }

    virtual int32_t Init() = 0;
    virtual bool Destroy() = 0;
    virtual bool Start() = 0;
    virtual bool Stop() = 0;
    virtual bool isRunning() = 0;
    virtual void Tick() = 0;

    template <class T>
    Object<T> CreateObject(T);
};
```

I am not sure how the call looks like though. I thought the following would be enough, where `mObjFactory` is an implementation of previously mentioned virtual class;

```
inline void AllocateWithMemPoolAux() {  mObjFactory->CreateObject<TestClass1>(); }
```

The error I get is **"No instance of function template matches the argument list"**
What does the proper function call look like?

(also - as a sidenote, is it okay to declare a template method in an interface and demand the user implement it? as you cannot declare it virtual)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice:

```
template <class T>
Object<T> CreateObject(T);
```

did you mean

```
template <class T>
Object<T> CreateObject();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because you're not passing an object of `TestClass1` to this method.

Properly compiling code would look like:

```
inline void AllocateWithMemPoolAux() 
{  
   TestClass1 tObj; 
   mObjFactory->CreateObject<TestClass1>(tObj); 
}
```

I assume your `AllocateWithMemPoolAux()` has more side-effects than shown here; at the minimum you need to do something with the return value of the `CreateObject` function (it may be better design to pass an object by reference into this function instead).

Answer (score 0):

a template function

```
template <class T>
Object<T> CreateObject(T);
```

takes one argument of type `T`. You called it without it.

Answer (score 0):

You called that method without an argument :

```
mObjFactory->CreateObject<TestClass1>();
```

you need to pass the object of type TestClass1 :

```
inline void AllocateWithMemPoolAux() {  mObjFactory->CreateObject<TestClass1>(TestClass1()); }
```